# Clojure: number of consecutive repetition items

Tags: clojure

I need a function to calculate the number of consecutive equal entries in a sequence. For example, (consecutive "abcdefg") should return 0, while (consecutive "aabcdddefg") should return 3.

Is the way i wrote it idiomatic or could it be improved?

```
(defn consecutive [p]
  (second (reduce
            #(vector %2
                     (if (= (first %1) %2)
                       (inc (second %1))
                       (second %1)))
            [nil 0]
            p)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
user> (defn consecutive [s] (->> s (partition-by identity) (reduce #(+ % (dec (count %2))) 0)))
#'user/consecutive
user> (consecutive "abcdefg")
0
user> (consecutive "aabcdddefg")
3
```

I prefer the `(partition-by identity)` idiom when some consecutive sequences are required.

Answer (score 5):

I think that `(consecutive "abcdefg")` should return 1, not 0.

Here's a simple implementation that achieves this:

```
(defn consecutive [s] 
  (apply max (map count (partition-by identity s))))
```

Comment: Why should `(consecutive "abcdefg")` return 1? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Because the longest consecutive sequence of characters is length one (a single character). It seems logically inconsistent to force the result to be zero in this case. I'd argue that the only case where you have zero consecutive characters is an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
(defn consecutive [string]
  (let [n (apply max (map count (partition-by identity string)))]
    (if (= n 1) 0 n)))
```

it's common pattern